# Regular Expression exercise

Tags: regex, regular-language

```
L= { w is {1,2,3}* 
   | w starts with 3, ends with 2 and there is a substring of only 1 with length 
       even equal or >2}.
```

So result of some tests must be:

```
3323112: accepted
311211112: non accepted
31112: non accepted
32: non accepted
2113: non accepted
313212: non accepted
```

My answer is : `3*(11)*2*`

But it fails some tests... Can someone help me?

The 2nd exercise is :

```
L= { w is {1,2}* 
   | in w after every 1 there is one or more 2, but if the 1 is the last 
     character it could be the last (no 2 after it)}
```

Test strings:

```
1: accepted
222:  accepted
221212122:  accepted
1222121:  accepted
111221: not  accepted
11: not  accepted
```

My solution is `(12*)*`

But it fails some tests... Help me please.

Comment: I suspect this question belongs on [cstheory.se]

Comment: Why is `311211112` rejected in the first exercise? It satisfies all the conditions you listed (starts with 3, ends with 2, and contains a sequence of 1s with even length).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to do your homework for you but I'll point out a few problems with what you are trying to do:

- A star on its own is not a wildcard. It does not mean "match anything". It is a *quantifier* that *modifies* the previous token. You want to use `.*` instead of `*` to allow any number of any characters.
- The expression `.*(11)*.*` also matches strings with an odd number of 1s, because the `.` can also be one. The digit immediately before and after the 1s must be "not-a-1" (i.e. 2 or 3).

Hopefully this should help you.

Answer (score 1):

- Starts with a 3: `^3`
- Ends with a 2: `2$`
- Contains a sequence of at least two 1s: `1{2,}`
- Resulting regex: `^3[1-3]*1{2,}[1-3]*2$` (the `[1-3]*` pieces allow for any digits 1 to 3 in there, since there are no requirements there)
- EDIT: I think I misunderstood the condition about the 1s,
  so the pattern for that is: `(?<!1)(1{2})+(?!1)` (lookbehind and lookahead to ensure 1s are isolated)
- Revised pattern: `^3[1-3]*(?<!1)(1{2})+(?!1)[1-3]*2$`

---

- After every 1 there is at least one 2: `(?<!1)12+` (ensure there are no 1s before this one)
- The final 1 might not have a 2 after: `1?$`
- Result: `^((?<!1)12+)*1?$`

---

Hope this helps. Good luck with regexes, they're hard to learn but easy once you get the hang of it.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the condition about the 1s. Does it mean the sequence of ones must have a length that's an even number?

Comment: @Kolink That's how I interpreted it. I think it must be even, yes.

Comment: It says "a substring of only 1 with length even" in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems like homework I'm not gonna give a straight answer. You'll want to look into the modifiers in regular expressions. `*` denotes a repetition of 0 or more times. There's also `+`, `?` and square brackets for character classes. Also note that some stuff that's available may be dependent on the regex parser (often called "flavour") you're using. But some basics are normally the same.

Good luck!